# Javascript NaN function not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate a text box to enter only numbers and not alphabets using **javascript NaN function**.
   But i am not getting the correct output

```html
<html>
<body>


<input type="text" id="demo">

<button onclick="myFunction();">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() 
{

var x =document.getElementById("demo");
   if (isNaN(x))
     {
      alert("hi");
     }
    else
    {
    alert("world");
    }
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").value` - you need to get the value from the input, not the input itself

Comment: The output is correct. Your expectations apparently are not.

Comment: in your example x is holding the element not the element value, change it to document.getElementById("demo").value

Comment: `<form>
  Only Numbers: <input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[0-9]" title="Three letter country code">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
` Try this code it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

`x` in your code will be an `HTMLInput` object. It will never be a number.

You want to test the value of `parseInt(x.value)`.